# Мерцание текста на Android

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, color

Здравствуйте, мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку TextView мигнул бы один раз красным. Делаю игру и хочу, чтобы когда не хватает денег на то или ионе действие, мерцало поле с деньгами, подсказывая пользователю, что у него нету денег.
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: А как Вы пробовали реализовать данную задачу? Решается в одну строчку.

Comment: Здравствуйте, а в какую одну строчку?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариантов решения много, например через анимацию такой:

```
//анимация альфа канала (прозрачности от 0 до 1)
Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
//длительность анимации 1/10 секунды
animation.setDuration(100);
//сдвижка начала анимации (с середины)
animation.setStartOffset(50);
//режим повтора - сначала или в обратном порядке
animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
//режим повтора (бесконечно)
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
//накладываем анимацию на TextView
myTextView.startAnimation(animation);
```